# Concern with location sevices on previously owned iPad

Tags: ipad, gps, geolocation

I bought an iPad off of Craigslist, I wiped it clean and set it up as my own. Is there any way that the previous owner can view my location? Either with MobileMe or find my iPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Since you (presumably) set up your account on the device, they no longer have control over it via Find My iPad.